# NiFi: ReplaceText alternatives to modify JSON

Tags: apache-nifi

My NiFi application receives two kinda different types of JSON's.
First of them looks like:

```
[
  {
    "campaign": {
      "resourceName": "customers/8952771329/campaigns/11381694617",
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "name": "Saint_Spring_Active Minerals_oct-nov_2020_trueview_skip_5766500views",
      "id": "11381694617"
    },
    "metrics": {
      "interactionEventTypes": [
        "VIDEO_VIEW"
      ],
      "clicks": "6",
      "videoQuartileP100Rate": 0.44493171079034244,
      "videoQuartileP25Rate": 0.9747718298919024,
      "videoQuartileP50Rate": 0.7339309987701469,
      "videoQuartileP75Rate": 0.5337562301767105,
      "videoViewRate": 0.4471109114825628,
      "videoViews": "27872",
      "viewThroughConversions": "0",
      "contentBudgetLostImpressionShare": 0.0000013066088274492382,
      "contentImpressionShare": 0.0999,
      "contentRankLostImpressionShare": 0.9001,
      "conversionsValue": 0,
      "conversions": 0,
      "costMicros": "9338700950",
      "ctr": 0.00009624947864865732,
      "currentModelAttributedConversions": 0,
      "currentModelAttributedConversionsValue": 0,
      "engagementRate": 0,
      "engagements": "0",
    },
    "segments": {
      "device": "CONNECTED_TV",
      "date": "2020-12-20"
    }
  }
]
```

And second:

```
[
  {
    "adGroup": {
      "resourceName": "customers/5404177717/adGroups/110501283582",
      "campaign": "customers/5404177717/campaigns/11628802542"
    },
    "metrics": {
      "interactionEventTypes": [
        "CLICK"
      ],
      "clicks": "1",
      "averageCpm": 95497428.02172929,
      "gmailForwards": "0",
      "gmailSaves": "0",
      "gmailSecondaryClicks": "0",
      "impressions": "4418",
      "interactionRate": 0.00022634676324128565,
      "interactions": "1"
    },
    "adGroupAd": {
      "resourceName": "customers/5404177717/adGroupAds/110501283582~480227690139",
      "status": "ENABLED",
      "ad": {
        "resourceName": "customers/5404177717/ads/480227690139",
        "id": "480227690139",
        "name": "20 sec perek"
      },
      "adGroup": "customers/5404177717/adGroups/110501283582"
    },
    "segments": {
      "device": "DESKTOP",
      "date": "2020-11-21"
    }
  }
]
```

I already have 2 tables in my database to save this data. I have an attribute `table.name` just to not create same block where's only table name is different.

My next block is `FlattenJson`. After this i'm using `ReplaceText` with search value (replacement value is empty string): `(customers\\\/${client.customer.id}\\\/campaigns\\\/|customers\\\/${client.customer.id}\\\/adGroups\\\/)`.

Why this? From this line: `"adGroup": "customers/5404177717/adGroups/110501283582"` i only need last value `110501283582` as ad_group_id. And from this line: `"campaign": "customers/5404177717/campaigns/11628802542"` i only need `11628802542`. `${client.customer.id}` can be different, so i'm using EL features.

Also i need to change json value name `adGroup` to `ad.group.id`, for this i'm also using `ReplaceText`.

Can i do it faster without two `ReplaceText` processors?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following processors...I think using them can be an alternative:

**JoltTransformJSON**:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/

**UpdateRecord**:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html